# Determinant of a Matrix given the Characteristic Equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If the characteristic polynomial of a matrix A is...

p(λ)=(λ+1) (λ−2)^2 (λ+3)^2

Find det(A^−1).

Thanks!

Comment: It would be good to know how do you define the characteristic polynomial. Not everyone defines it the same way. But, up to sign, it it is the constant term of the polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**

The characteristic polynomial has the form

$$\det(\lambda I-A)=\lambda^n-a_{n-1}\lambda^{n-1}+\cdots+(-1)^n\det(A)$$
and we have

$$\det(A^{-1})=\frac1{\det(A)}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes, much thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The determinant is the product of eigenvalues.

The determinant of the inverse is the inverse of the determinant.

The eigenvalues are :

> $\{-1,~ 2,~ 2,~ -3,~ -3\}$

So the determinant is :

> $-1 \times 2 \times 2 \times -3 \times -3 = -36$

So the determinant of the inverse is :

> $-\frac 1{36}$

Comment: The eigenvalues being the "zero's" of the characteristic, correct?

Comment: @TimConklin Yes, that is correct.